# how do I pass an argument as a method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I am trying to make a function that takes $scope and appends it with the method 'telegraph'. the problem is, $scope takes the method "tag" without replacing it with the argument.
So instead of reading "$scope.telegraph" it is run as "$scope.tag"

```
function httpRequest(url,tag){
  $http({
  method: 'JSONP',
  url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&q="+url+"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK"

    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // data contains the response
      $scope.tag = data.responseData.feed.entries;
      console.log(tag);

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      });
 }

httpRequest('http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/rss','telegraph');{}
```

Comment: Could you please re-word your question? What do you mean by "taking method"s and "replacing by arguments"?

Comment: I hope that is clearer. English is not my forte

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but maybe what you're looking for is `$scope[tag]` instead of `$scope.tag`

Comment: Regarding the wording it might be worth noting that 'tag' and 'telegrapgh' are the names of _properties_ here. To a property you can assign a method, a string, an object or any kind of a _value_.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I assume, you want to set the value of $scope.telegraph (e.g. the tag) to response you get from the call; it should be like this:

```
$scope[tag] = data.responseData.feed.entries;
```

Comment: @user3784864 'Thanks, this helped me' is spelled 'vote up' here ;-)

Comment: @fast: You are very right. But one needs at least 15 reps to upvote. All they can do is accept and say "Thank you" for now :)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `someObj.someProp` is equivalent to `someObj['someProp']` (i.e. accessing the property 
named `someProp` of the object referenced by `someObj`).

---

In your case, `$scope.tag` is equivalent to `$scope['tag']`, i.e. accessing a property named `tag` (which is not what you want).

You need to use the array notation:

```
$scope[tag] = data.responseData.feed.entries;
```

<sub>This uses `tag` as a variable (holding the string `telegraph`) and **not** as the string `tag`.

Thus it is equivalent to `$scope[tag] --> $scope['telegraph'] --> $scope.telegraph`.</sub>

Comment: Yes you are right. thats brilliant. thanks for the explanation. I'm only gonna learn more.